# Is there an explicit formula for the eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix $J$ of a strongly regular graph $G$ of degree $k$ )?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let's recall the definition of a strongly regular graph. Let $G$ be a regular graph of degree $k$ with $v$ vertices. G is said to be strongly regular if there are integers $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that:

Every two adjacent vertices have $\lambda$  common neighbours.

Every two non-adjacent vertices have $\mu$ common neighbours.

It is well known that $J$ admits three distincts eigenvalues:

$k$ with multiplicity 1.

$r = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \left( \lambda -\mu\right) + \sqrt{\left( \lambda -\mu\right)^2+4\left( k -\mu\right)} \right]$
with multiplicity $f = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(v - 1\right) - \frac{2k+\left(v-1\right)\left(\lambda - \mu\right)}{\sqrt{\left( \lambda -\mu\right)^2+4\left( k -\mu\right)}} \right]$.

$s = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \left( \lambda -\mu\right) - \sqrt{\left( \lambda -\mu\right)^2+4\left( k -\mu\right)} \right]$
with multiplicity $g = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(v - 1\right) + \frac{2k+\left(v-1\right)\left(\lambda - \mu\right)}{\sqrt{\left( \lambda -\mu\right)^2+4\left( k -\mu\right)}} \right]$.

One of the eigenvectors associated to the adjacency matrix is known, the $\left(v \times 1\right)$ vector $(1, \dots, 1)$.

**Are there explicit formula for the other eigenvectors of $J$?**

I have looked into several books on spectral graph theory which seem to be silent on this point. In particular the book by D.M Cvetkovic, M. Doob and H. Sachs, *Spectra of Graphs. Theory and applications*. (1995) but also the book by E. Brouwer and H. Van Maldeghem, *Strongly Regular Graphs* (2022) and finally D.M Cvetkovic, P.Rowlinson, S. Simic, *Eigenspace of graphs* (2008).

Comment: Am I guessing rigtht that it should be somewhat clear that $(\lambda-\mu)^2+4(k-\mu)$ is a perfect square?